# Binary Search Tree leaf count issue

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I desperately need help finding the problem in my code, I'm sure it's narrowed down to the countLeaves function. I can't seem to get it to print out no matter how I alter it. I'm pretty new to C++ but I'd really appreciate anything anyone can offer me! I will post the header, function, and main in that order.

```
#include <iostream>

//#include<stack>
//#include<queue>
#ifndef BSTFunction
#define BSTFunction
using namespace std;
typedef int num;

class Node{
public:
    num info;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Node(); // Valuetype to num
    Node(num);
};

class BST{
public:
    Node* findNode(num);
    Node* findParent(num);
    Node* findrightnode(Node*);
    void inorder(Node*);
    Node* root;
    Node* curr;
    //Was public:
    BST();
    void insert(num);
    void inorderTraversal(); //was traverse
    num search();
    void custom_print();
    int countLeaves(Node* T);
};

#endif
```

Function.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include "BSTFunction.hpp"

Node::Node(){
    left=right=NULL;
}
Node::Node(num val){
    info=val;
    left=right=NULL;
}

//constructor
BST::BST(){
    root=curr=NULL;
}
//insert a node with value val in tree
void BST::insert(num val){
    if(root==NULL)
        root = new Node(val);
    else{
        Node* p =findNode(val);
        if(p==0) {
            //cout<<"fine1";
            Node* parent=root;
            if (p != root)
                parent = findParent(val);
            if(val>parent->info) parent->right=new Node(val);
            else parent->left=new Node(val);
        }//cout<<"fine2";
    }
}
//remove the node if value is val

//fins node with a value key
Node* BST::findNode(num key){
    Node* p =root;
    while((p!=NULL)&&(p->info!=key)){
        if(key<p->info)p=p->left;
        else p=p->right;
    }
    return p;
}
//find parent of a node with value key
Node* BST::findParent(num key){
    Node* p =root;
    Node* q=0;
    while((p!=NULL)&&(p->info!=key)){
        q=p;
        if(key<p->info)p=p->left;
        else p=p->right;
    }
    return q;
}
//finds the most right of a node p(means immediate succesor of p in inorder representation)
//Node* BST::findrightnode(Node* p){
//    Node* righty=p;
//    while(righty->right!=NULL)
//        righty=righty->right;
//    return righty;
//}

void BST::inorder(Node* p){
    if(p!=NULL){
        inorder(p->left);
        cout<<p->info<<" ";
        inorder(p->right); }
}
void BST::inorderTraversal(){
    cout<<endl<<"Inorder: ";
    inorder(root);
    cout<<endl;
}

//to print tree hightwise i.e. all nodes at h1, then all nodes at h2, then at h3
void BST::custom_print(){
    //Node* temp;
    if(root==NULL)
        return;
    queue<Node*> Q;
    Q.push(root);
    //Q.push(NULL);
    while(!Q.empty()){
        curr=Q.front();
        cout<<curr<<" ";
        Q.pop();
        Q.push(curr->left);
        Q.push(curr->right);
    }
}



int BST::countLeaves(Node *T)
{
    if(T ==NULL)      //if T is empty, return0
    {
        return(0);
    }
    else if(T -> left == NULL && T-> right == NULL)      //if T has0 children, then it is a leaf
    {
        return(1);
    }
    else
    {
        return countLeaves(T -> left) + countLeaves(T -> right);  //recursive call to find more leaves

    }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "BSTFunction.hpp"

int main()
{
    BST leaves;
    leaves.insert(24);
    leaves.insert(43); //The code will take all of these numbers entered into the main function and put them in traversal order, much like it could under any order (post or pre) if needed. (Note to self: Not needed for this assignment)
    leaves.insert(82);
    leaves.insert(22);
    leaves.insert(12);
    leaves.insert(92);
    leaves.insert(68);
    leaves.insert(20);
    leaves.insert(4);
    cout << "These are the in order leaves for the Bianary Search Tree. " << endl;
    leaves.inorderTraversal();
    cout << "The number of leaves are: " << endl;
    leaves.countLeaves()
    //leaves.custom_print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The trick is to call `inorder`, and instead of a simple `cout`, you can call a function to add 1 to the leaf count if there are no left and right children of the node.  Saying that, this is how you make `inorder` generic -- when a node is encountered, call a user-defined function passing the node encountered instead of just a simple `cout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you have an argument in your `countLeaves()` function-

```
int BST::countLeaves(Node *T)
```

> When you call this function from your main, it doesn't have an
>   argument to give to `countLeaves()`.  It throws an error as it doesn't
>   receive any parameter.

As for the solution, you'll have to create a Node object in your main and send it as an argument. You'll have to worry about what and how you are going to do all this. There seems to be a few errors both in logic and syntax. (I commented your `countLeaves()` call and it threw many errors. 
Recommend using debugger. 
Try to print values and "Function entered" print statements to make it easier to find mistakes in your program if you cannot use debugger at the moment.

Hope this was helpful.